# what is different between operator+ and operator[]

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

I am confused by the following sentence in our lectures

> By way of Functions of the Name `operator@` the named operator @
>   (excluding
>   = () [] ? : . -> .* ::) can be overloaded for datatypes that have not been 'built in'.

I realize that the operator @ refers to the likes of '+ - * / ^ ...etc', and I understand how and why these are overloaded. But I am annoyed by the "(excluding
= () [] ? : . -> .* ::)" part that is mentioned above. What is meant by it, and why are those said operators excluded?

I mean I declare

```
something operator+(something a, something b)
```

and I do not see a big difference in the way I declare

`something operator[] (something c)`

It is said that the likes of [], (), -> and = can only be overloaded with member functions, but the operator `+` that I mentioned above is also only overloaded via a member function, is it not?

Comment: You example of `operator+` is a free function, if it only took 1 arguments it would be a member function.

Comment: Please provide the context for this sentence. It's hard to know what it means without the context in which it was said.

Comment: Some operators can **only** be overloaded with member functions. Other operators can be overloaded with member functions **and** with non-member functions.

Comment: You should take this question to the person who made the claim, i.e. your teacher.

Comment: @super: It could be a free *unary* `operator+` with one argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to [overload operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators):

- as "free" function (i.e. non-member), outside of the class for which you want to overload them,
- as member function.

The link above clarifies in a nice table that the overload is possible in the form of member functions for  `=`, `()`, `[]`, and `->` but forbidden as free function.

In addition, the scope resolution operator `::` as well as member access `.`, member access trhough pointer to member `.*`, and the ternary conditional operator `x ? y : z` [cannot be overloaded](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#overload-dot) at all.

---

**Edit:** Here an [example](https://ideone.com/qqmHPP), with `operator*` defined as member function and `operator+` as non member function:

```
class Rational {
    int p; 
    int q; 
public:  
    Rational (int d=0, int n=1) : p{d}, q{n} { } 
    Rational operator*(const Rational& r) const {    // for curent object * r
        return Rational(p*r.p,q*r.q); 
    }
    int numerator() const {return p; }
    int denominator() const { return q; } 
}; 

Rational operator+(const Rational &a, const Rational &b) {   // for object a + object b
    return Rational(a.numerator()*b.denominator()+b.numerator()*a.denominator(),
                                                      a.denominator()*b.denominator());
}
```

Comment: and the difference between this free function and member is that the member function is declared in the class while the free function is not, correct?

Comment: @user9078057: That’s the definition of those terms, yes.

Comment: @user9078057 indeed.  I've edited to provide an example that highlight the difference.